# Monitoring of an active SMTP service on a website

Tags: ruby, sockets

I am trying to check if network services i.e. HTTP, HTTPs,TCP, SMTP, FTP, Telnet are activated on a website and running correctly without any breaks. I wrote the following code to open the TCP connection to the remote host on remote port and check if the connection can be established with the website.

```
require 'timeout'
require 'socket'

def ping(host,port)
 begin
  Timeout::timeout(5) do
   s=TCPSocket.new(host,port)    
   s.close 
   return true 
   end 
  rescue Err::ECONNREFUSED
   return false
  rescue Err::Timeout
   return false
 end
end
```

I also wrote code to monitor the SMTP service already running on a website.

```
smtp=Net::SMTP.start("mail.google.com",25).started?
```

But the output is false whereas gmail supports SMTP service. So the question is:

What should be  done to monitor the SMTP service already running on a website?